# please solve this select query in ms access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

[image]

[image]

Here is pics of Relationship and Pasenger_detail form and i wrote query to select seat_no but its not working properly. it is only showing all seats  as per bus reserved id. but requirement were to show only those which are not yet selected. here is query

```
    "Select seat_no.seat_no FROM Seat_No Where seat_no.seat_no <= (select br_info.Seats_Reserved from br_info where ((Br_info.br_id)=[forms]![pasenger_detail]![br_id]) AND (Seat_No.seat_no) NOT IN (SELECT Pasenger_Detail.Seat_No FROM Pasenger_Detail WHERE (((Pasenger_Detail.Group_ID)=[forms]![Pasenger_Detail]![Group_ID]) AND ((Pasenger_Detail.BR_ID)=[forms]![Pasenger_Detail]![BR_ID]))));"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT S.Seat_No 
FROM Seat_No AS S
WHERE S.Seat_No Not In
(
   SELECT P.Seat_No 
   FROM BR_Info AS B INNER JOIN Pasenger_Detail AS P ON B.BR_ID = P.BR_ID
   WHERE B.BR_ID = Forms!pasenger_detail!BR_ID
   AND B.Group_ID = Forms!Pasenger_Detail!Group_ID 
)
```

In the above query I am joining `BR_Info` and `Passenger_Detail` together.  It is an `INNER JOIN` which means that the record has to exist in both `BR_Info` and `Passenger_Detail` in order to be considered.  Then I am using `Not In` to get all the `Seat_No` that are not contained in the sub query.

Comment: kindly can u tell me what is difference b/w inner join (Joins) and subquery. are they two different techniques for same purpose

Comment: They are just two different ways to do something.  A join should run faster then severel nested levels of sub queries

Comment: boss your query is started working perfectly, earlier mine was also giving me some data. But current problem is very strange for me. as i enter data for three records it entered properly, but when i goes for fourth the seat_no combobox didnot showed me any thing. i tried many time for this but same problem. then i close database and rerun it. it start working but same happened after two three records. i think maybe it is due to lost_focus event beacuse i wrote that query in that event. am i need to write query in any other event or any other problem is there. any suggestions please.

Comment: sorry for late reply because it was too late night for me yesterday i have to go for bed to meet next day activities. please.

Comment: Boss Linger, i have applied your query it partially worked. earlier i thought it working fine but as soon as i goes to third record it stuck. nothing showed in seat no combobox. as well as when i througly go through from listed data in combobox i realized its showing seat nos from 1 to 100 and not showing those which are being selected by me. but earlier in my query it is also showing seat nos from 1 to the value stored in Seat_reserved field of BR_info table.